# Find Prime Numbers based on user input

Tags: java

I have these two methods that i am using to find prime numbers based on user input, i have a method called isPrime that logically should return true if a number is prime, however it always return true no matter what the number is? 
I realise there are plenty of answers similar to my query but none have helped so far.

```
public static void userPrimes(){
    int[] tempPrimes = new int[49];
    int primesFound = 0;
    //Input Amount of numbers to be analysed
    int[] initial  = new int[Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Amount of numbers to be checked")) -1];
    //Input Values
    for(int i = 0; i<initial.length; i++){
        initial[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number at position:" + (i+1)));
        if (initial[i] > 49){
            initial[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numbers cannot be greater than 49, Try again:"));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<initial.length; i++){
        if (isPrime(initial[i]) == true){
            tempPrimes[i] = initial[i];
            primesFound++;
        }
    }
    int[] finalPrimes = new int[primesFound];
    for (int i=0;i<finalPrimes.length;i++){
        finalPrimes[i] = tempPrimes[i];
        System.out.print(finalPrimes[i] + " ");
    }
}

//checks whether an int is prime or not.
static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for(int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
        if(n % j == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Your `isPrime(int n)` looks fine itself. Listen to @OliCharlesworth!

Comment: I did try that, i just don't have a lot of experience with the debugger! I'll bear this in mind for the future, thanks for the friendly advice guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems in your code:

1.

```
int[] initial  = new int[Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Amount of numbers to be checked")) -1];
```

The array should be in length of the amount that the user entered, not minus 1

2.

```
 if (isPrime(initial[i]) == true){
        tempPrimes[i] = initial[i];
        primesFound++;}
```

You should put the primes in the temp primes array in tempPrimes[primesFound]

Also, your final loop is not useful.You can do the printing in the previous loop

Comment: My initial thinking for the minus one was that the user would want lets say 10 values, and if this was the array size there would technically be 11 values available so minus 1 would remedy that. I see now how thats not ideal though! thanks for the help i changed that loop and that seemed to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your isPrime function is fine but as performance wise is concerned you need to iterate till half of the  number rather than iterating till number

```
boolean x = isPrime(13);
System.out.println(x);

static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        for(int j = 2; j <= n/2; j++) {
            if(n % j == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

returns true and passing 14 returns false..it works perfect here..

might be the problem is with your loop code which is calling this method

Comment: Thanks for the help, efficiency is always something i want to develop further!

Comment: Actually, you only need to iterate up to the square root of the number because any factor > sqrt(n) has a cofactor <= sqrt(n).  Also, after checking for divisibility by 2 you need only check potential factors which are odd, so you can iterate from 3 to sqrt(n) with increments of 2.

Answer (score 0):

modify this line by by removing -1
no need to do minus 1 as it reduces the no of input to user by one .

if user inputs amount as 3 then -1 makes him to enter only 2 numbers. so make it as below

```
int[] initial  = new int[Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                                ("Enter Amount of numbers to be checked"))];
```

use only one loop as below to print all prime numbers

```
 for(int i = 0; i<initial.length; i++){

            if (isPrime(initial[i]) == true){
                tempPrimes[i] = initial[i];
                System.out.println(tempPrimes[i]);

                }
        }
```